# create dropdown with associative array

Tags: yii

I'm trying to create a dynamic dropdown from my database. i noticed when i query using Yii my it **doesn't** return an array in this format `array(1=>1, 2=>2...)` which i need for my `CHtml::dropDownList()`

so i added a for loop to do so. is this correct or following the framework standards? or am i missing something? sorry pretty new to yii

in my model

```
 public function cDropdown()
        {
            $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `code`, `name`
                    FROM `AB` 
                    GROUP BY `code` 
                    ORDER BY `name` ASC";

            $query = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();

            $arr = array();

            foreach($query AS $name=>$value)
                $arr[$value['code']] = $value['name'];

            return $arr;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a very much simpler way by using like this: `$form->dropDownList($model, 'attribute', CHtml::listData(ModelName::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'));`

The `id` and the `name`, should be replaced by the fields you want in the dropdown. The id will be the value, and the name will be displayed.

You can also change the `findAll()` and use another method you want.

Okay? Good luck